# Excel VBA - Create a new row every 1200 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro that simply adds a row to my data set every 1200 rows.

I have tried using a For Step loop with no avail.

Please let me know if any other information is required.

Thanks!

Edit:
Step 1200

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim lngLast_Row As Long
Dim lngRow As Long

lngLast_Row = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For lngRow = 1 To lngLast_Row Step 1259
    Range.Select
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = lngRow
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If you edit your question to include the code that isn't working, we might be able to spot the problem.

Comment: do you mean to **insert** a row? Also, not sure why you use "Step 1259" instead of Step 1200?

Answer (score 1):

*We need to be careful about where to start, how to step, and where to stop.* OP's need isn't completely defined in the question. My bet is that OP wants n data rows, 1 blank row, n data rows, etc.

Here's a sub to do this:

```
Public Sub SplitDataRowsInIslandsOf(ByVal plNumRowsPerIsland As Long, ByVal prngFirstDataCell As Excel.Range)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim insertRow As Long

    With prngFirstDataCell.Worksheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, prngFirstDataCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'In calculating the loop's upper bound, account for the rows that will be inserted,
    'and avoid operating past the last data row.
    lastRow = lastRow + ((lastRow - prngFirstDataCell.Row + 1) \ plNumRowsPerIsland) - 1

    For insertRow = (prngFirstDataCell.Row + plNumRowsPerIsland) To lastRow Step (plNumRowsPerIsland + 1)
        prngFirstDataCell.Worksheet.Cells(insertRow, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Next
End Sub
```

For islands of 1'200 rows, if the first cell in a column containing data (reallly, any column that can be used to detect the last data row) is `H2` on the active worksheet, one would call:

```
SplitDataRowsInIslandsOf 1200, ActiveSheet.Range("H2")
```

Of course, we shouldn't be using Active(xyz), but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used VB but I deal with a lot of C# programs, I just wanna help you with this pseudocode if you can get an idea.

```
 void addRow(Excel worksheet)
 {    
   int countRows = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; //All used rows


   for (int i = 1; i < countRows; i++)
   {
       if (i % 1200 == 0)
       {
         worksheet.Rows[i].Insert();
       }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it's better if you don't rely on `ActiveSheet`, instead use fully qualified version, like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim lngLast_Row As Long
Dim lngRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change "Sheet1" to your sheet's name (don't rely on ActiveSheet)
    lngLast_Row = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For lngRow = 1 To lngLast_Row Step 1200
        .Rows(lngRow).Insert ' add a row every 1200 rows
        .Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = lngRow ' value of column B of the new row
    Next
End With

End Sub
```